# Visual Studio with StackExchange or StackOverflow

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

On a Microsoft Video presentation that I just watched, I saw that there is an StackOverflow tool on the upper right corner of Visual Studio IDE. Near the Quick SearchBar.

I don't know what kind of tool it is, if it is a search for help toolbar or shortcut to StackOverflow or StackExchange.

Anyway, I am really interested of what this toolbar does. Please redirect me to any possible path from where I can obtain it or an article for it.

Comment: Could you link to the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely coming from [VSCommands](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece), a Visual Studio Extension that adds (among many other things) a SO toolbar to the top right of the IDE.

Unfortunately, the [Features](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features-Stackoverflow) page on their website that details the SO toolbar is mislinked, and ends up going to Touch support instead. However, [this](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/release-notes/3.0.2) blog post details the feature when it was released in v3.0

It's a pretty neat extension, I primarily use it for showing the Branch of the solution in the Window Title.

Comment: Wow Neat. Thanks for the link.